# Cloning row that uses RadioButtonFor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor

I have a row that looks like this

```
@for (int i = 0; i < item.IHP.Count; i++)
{
   Part part = db.Parts.Find(Model.Parts[i].ID);
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].ID)
   <tr class="tr_clone">

        <td>
            @part.PartIDLink
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].MFGNumber)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].MFGNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
        </td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold">
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" class="part-class" data-partId="@(part.ID)" checked>
        </td>
        @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType)
            </td>
        }
     </tr>
}
```

And here is my Jquery Code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () {
                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
                var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                var $clone = $tr.clone();
                $clone.find('td');
                $tr.after($clone);
                $($clone).find(".part-class").hide();
            });
        });
```

Currently, when the row is cloned it puts both rows into one big radio group. How can I make it so that they are in separate radio groups?

Comment: Change the `name` attribute on the cloned radios to be different. I think you asked a similar question before and I noted that you're going to have repeated IDs... Repeated names cause problems too.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this, would you be able to provide a quick example?

Comment: `$clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", function (el) { return el.name + Date.now(); });`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Awesome. Thanks!